# How to connect protractor js test with slack to send hook after testing?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, protractor, slack

How to connect **protractor** js test with slack to send hook after testing?

Comment: use `slack-node` module from npm. refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack-node.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj: What is Slack ?

Comment: Do you have a simple example how test file should look?

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj

Answer (score 2):

One way to have Protractor hit a [Slack webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks) is to use the [`onComplete` block in your config](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts). Here's an example that uses [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) to send the request to Slack:

```
// ...
onComplete: function() {
    var rp = require('request-promise');

    var options = {
        uri : 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/YOUR_SLACK_WEBHOOK',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            'attachments': [{
                'title': 'E2E Test Results'
            }]

        },
        channel: '#YOUR_SLACK_CHANNEL',
        username: 'TestBot',
        mrkdwn: true,
        json: true
    };

    // send to slack...
    return rp(options)
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
},
```

Install `request-promise`, add the block to your Protractor config, **add your Slack webhook uri and channel** name, and run your test using the config. You'll have to do some homework to tweek it to your liking, but that's the jist.

Answer (score -2):

```
    let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: [
    'spec.js'
  ],
  onPrepare: function () {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      }
    }));
  },

  onComplete: function() {
    var rp = require('request-promise');

    var options = {
        uri : 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/YOUR_SLACK_WEBHOOK',
        method: 'POST',
        body: {
            'attachments': [{
                'title': 'E2E Test Results'
            }]

        },
        channel: '#YOUR_SLACK_CHANNEL',
        username: 'TestBot',
        mrkdwn: true,
        json: true
    };

    // send to slack...
    rp(options)
        .then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
};
```